# Managing Unity Scenes during refactoring?

Tags: unity, c#

Most of my Unity project code is in a visual studio project, and I use Unity for UI/Rendering/wiring things together.

I renamed some fields in an object and suddenly the game, when run in unity, became unrunnably buggy. It turned out that a field I had set in the unity frontend had been unset when I renamed it.

What's a good way to avoid these sorts of problems when working with unity? I was using version control and could have reverted to an old build in the worst case, but I couldn't find any human-readable Unity Scene files that could have just shown me what I changed.

Comment: With regard to human-readability, do you know how to force Unity to use [text serialization for its scene & project settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/TextSceneFormat.html)?

Answer (score 9):

For refactoring fields check out the `FormerlySerializedAs` attribute. See: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Serialization.FormerlySerializedAsAttribute.html

When changing class names make sure that the file and the respective meta file is also renamed accordingly.

Comment: Oh fantastic, I didn't know this was a thing. Awesome. I've just always been careful to not rename my fields, or if I do, know that they're going to get untethered, and fix 'em.